# Browser app to connect to several sshd

Tags: browser, architecture, ssh

I would like to draft a browser application which can connect to ~20 remote sshd. Per ssh connection multiple commands should be handled. After restarting the browser, the several running jobs should be displayed in the browser again.
How would you construct the application ? The application should run on a Raspberry Pi. So utilization is limited.

Comment: `How would you construct the application?` I would do some research and probably write some code.

Comment: Is it a web browser application you are going to build? And will it have server side application serving the browser?

Comment: Yes server side applications can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Check the wikepedia page for [web based SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH). The basic idea is to have JavaScript on client to submit commands to server side web application. And server side application will connect to several different server sshd as proxy to send command and receive output.

Personally I will suggest to use WebSocket to implement the communication between client and server. But not sure what's the OS you will have and what library and programming language will be handy for you.